# css div children inside absolute div parent

Tags: html, css

kinda newbie question to css.

I have a centered div parent ( center of my screen ) using `position:absolute`
Now I want to create children divs inside my parent div. 
They should have:

- full height of parent
- diffrent width (should add up to width of parent)
- maybe padding, but that I should be able to add myself

Much like different sized columns.

What I've so far (parent div only, because everything I've tried was really messed up :( ):

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 75%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000000;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe add that "everything I've tried was really messed up" here so that we can picture out your issue...

Comment: Give us more background what you've done. Have you tried flex box? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One advice. DO not use `position:absolute` for layout. Only when necessary. THere are many ways to arrange your elements not just position:absolute.

Not really sure what you ' messed up ' but you can use flexbox -> add `display:flex` on parent and arrange your child divs inside it however you want

Read here more about [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and on other tutorials

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 75%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child1 {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.child2 {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.child3 {
  background: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child child1">text with padding</div>
 <div class="child child2">no padding</div>
 <div class="child child3">no padding</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, solved it myself right now using flexboxes... Any advise what I can use to replace my position:absoulte box

Comment: @bigsmokecriminal well that depends on what you want to do. How you need/want your layout to look like. Keep in mind that position:absolute positions the element relative to the first parent with a position set. So not always relative to the body/html

Comment: I want my parent box to be in the center of my screen. I've searched on stackoverflow and many ppl suggested to use position:absolute

Comment: Is your parent directly under 'body' ? or does it have other parents ?